# Connecting two identical mosfets in series

Tags: mosfet

[image]

I'm required to prove the above claim. I've written a few equations in my attempt to prove that and some of them obviously might not make sense.Could you tell me please if I'm in the right direction or do I have to come up with an entirely different approach ?  Here is my attempt :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will re-write the same comment that I wrote under your previous (now deleted?) question: 1) What defines if a MOSFET is in saturation or linear mode? 2) How does that apply to the circuit with 2 MOSFETs in series?

Comment: Can anybody provide further guidance on that problem ? I've not managed to understand the above tips...